# IDBCommand.ExecuteReader() not picking up SQL Server trace flags

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, executereader, idatareader

I am running a long query, and using trace flag 2312 in SQL Server.

I've noted that

- when using this trace flag my query returns all results at once, after roughly 20 minutes.
- when not using this trace flag my query returns rows continuously, finishing after roughly 30 minutes.

This is reflected when I make this call to `IDBCommand.ExecuteReader()`, with the trace flag this function completes after 20 minutes, without the trace flag the function completes immediately.

My problem is I get the expected trace flag behaviour if I manually add it as an option to my query like `Select * from table option (querytraceon 2312)`. However, I tried to set the trace flag for the db server globally `DBCC traceon(2312, -1)` and confirmed that the flag was active using `DBCC tracestatus()`. However, when I then try to create my reader using the query `Select * from table`, the `ExecuteReader()` call finishes immediately, and I can tell that this trace flag is somehow not being picked up.

Comment: Folks here are going to have the same questions we had for you on DBA.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's currently being asked on DBA.stackexchange.com by the same user. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223857/difference-in-behaviour-between-dbcc-traceon-and-querytraceon#223857

Comment: @Zane, you're right, turns out this is in fact just a sql server issue where I was using a cached plan. Thanks!

Comment: No problem man. Glad we were able to help out.